# Close multiple vim buffers interactively?

Tags: vim

After a while having a text editor open, especially after performing a fairly substantial refactor that touches a large number of files, you end up with a lot of buffers open.

In emacs I had become accustomed to using `kill-some-buffers`, which basically starts in interactive yes/no session, presenting each buffer's name and allowing you to press <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd> to either keep or delete each buffer, until all buffers have been presented to you (or you cancel the command).

Is there a way to do the equivalent in vim?  I can use a wildcard, but the filenames are all ruby files with different names (basically every file in my project).  Easiest thing is for me to just close *all* buffers and start over, but that's not really the solution I'm looking for, just for my own future reference.

If I could open a split window with a list of all the buffers and "mark" each buffer I want to close in some way, then "commit" that decision, that would work too.  Basically just something that doesn't require me to apply thought-provoking logic to the process of closing a bucket-load of buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the plugin [buffet](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3896) which allows similar things:

- Use `:Bufferlist` to open the list of buffers.
- Move up and down with the usual keys (`j`, `k`).
- Delete the buffer under cursor with `d`

I think that is similar enough to mark the buffer for deletion.

Comment: This looks good, thanks!  I had searched but didn't find this before :)